# types of user in android application

Tags: android

I'm currently making an offline application for android. Is it possible to have two types of users - admin and nonAdmin? The admin is the one who will add data to the application while the nonAdmin will just view data from the application.

If it is possible, how can I update the data of the nonAdmin if the admin had added new data to the application?

Comment: Please be more specific, do you want an application, that prompts the user for login on startup and showing different interfaces depending on the choosen user profile? Do you want to program an app that is used by multiple users on the same device? If a non Admin changes data, a other user can login and then would the the updated data, because its loaded after login.

Comment: You can write your own program that has that and define a way to get into admin mode. There is no way to automate this, you're going to have to do it yourself.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? There's no restriction within Android which would prevent you from having different types of users for your app.

Comment: I don't have a problem on the log-in part of the users. What I'm asking is about the changes will occur if the admin adds new data to the application. My application is offline, whenever the admin adds data to the application (the data will be added to the database), does this change the database of the application installed in the other phones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is possible. What kind of data do you want to add?

To get started use two buttons "Admin" and "User" in your first view which is shown when the application is started.

"Admin" starts the AdminActivity to add data. This could be stored in Key-Value pairs, an SQLiteDatabase or directly to the internal storage - depending on what kind of data you want to add.

"User" starts a read-only perspective of your application, showing the data added by the admin.

Comment: The application only determines the type of user during log-in. I don't have two views. If he/she log-ins as an admin, he/she can't switch to user mode. For example, I have two phones (A and B) then I install the app into my two phones. In my A phone, I'm an admin and on the other phone, I'm a "user". Whenever I added data as an admin, does the data in the other phone (the user) changes?

Comment: The data in the other phone? I thought we were talking about an app installed on a single device with multiple user types. How to synchronize data in an offline application between multiple devices? That's rather impossible...